# How to check if the JSON Object array contains the value defined or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

hello im a newbie in javascript ,
I need to check if the Object value is listed in the JSON  or not. If the yes do something else do another thing.

first i get JSON from ipapi.co/json which return this for example

Thanks Problem Solved!

Comment: You need/should define "strict"/exact filter criterias. To match "Neuviz Net" & "neuviz" is not a good solution and screams for false positiv results

Comment: What's the point of stringifying the live objects? It would be extremely hard to get the wanted values out of the strings.

Comment: @Teemu i gues it was a attempt for a simple `==` "filter",  but your right. Would be difficult so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine basic array/object functions to archive your goal.
But as i commented on your question, you should define strict filter criterias.

```js
const data = {
    "ip": "103.26.208.254",
    "version": "IPv4",
    "city": "Jakarta",
    "region": "Jakarta",
    "region_code": "JK",
    "country": "ID",
    "country_name": "Indonesia",
    "country_code": "ID",
    "country_code_iso3": "IDN",
    "country_capital": "Jakarta",
    "country_tld": ".id",
    "continent_code": "AS",
    "in_eu": false,
    "postal": null,
    "latitude": -6.1741,
    "longitude": 106.8296,
    "timezone": "Asia/Jakarta",
    "utc_offset": "+0700",
    "country_calling_code": "+62",
    "currency": "IDR",
    "currency_name": "Rupiah",
    "languages": "id,en,nl,jv",
    "country_area": 1919440.0,
    "country_population": 267663435.0,
    "asn": "AS18103",
    "org": "Neuviz Net"
};

// create a regex of each filter value
const filters = [
    "republik",
    "telekomunikasi",
    "fastnet", "indosatm2",
    "telekomunikasi", "indosat",
    "cyberindo", "biznet", "xl",
    "telematika", "hutchison",
    "smartfren", "mnc",
    "wireless indonesia",
    "antar nusa", "biznet",
    "ezecom", "win", "axis",
    "linknet-fastnet", "indonesia",
    "bali", "linknet", "indosat",
    "antar nusa", "indo", "firstmedia",
    "s.i", "cambodia", "neuviz"
].map((v) => {
    return new RegExp(`${v}`, "gi");
});


// get array of values from object
// filter array based on the test criteria
let matches = Object.values(data).filter((v) => {

    // conver every value to astring
    let value = String(v).toLowerCase();

    // test each filter on value
    return filters.some((filter) => {

        // test the regular expression on the value
        return filter.test(value);

    });

});


if (matches.length > 0) {

    console.log("Filter matched!", matches);

} else {

    console.log("Filte *not* matched")

}
```

The code is well documented, if you dont understand a snippet/chunk, let me know.
If it dosnt work like expected, let me know too!

Happy coding!

Comment: anyway , i think this "const / let" doesnt work well with android app, because im trying to build android app webview and its not working , but on browser its work perfectly..

Comment: @KuroyukiHime You didnt mention that anywhere, but feel free to change this to `var` or whatever you like.

Comment: can you show me how ? because im not really good at javascript .. thanks for your help.

Comment: As i have written, just use `var` instead of `const` / `let`...

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JavaScript have some in-build methods which you can do specific tasks with, like the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method in which you can check if one or more parts of the ISP names are partly in the list. It will return `true` or `false` which you can use to determine the text of your `$("#ip")` element.

```
$.getJSON("https://ipapi.co/json/", function (data) {

  // Create a list of organizations.
  var organizations = ["republik","telekomunikasi","fastnet","indosatm2","telekomunikasi","indosat","cyberindo","biznet","xl","telematika","hutchison","smartfren","mnc","wireless indonesia","antar nusa","biznet","ezecom","win","axis","linknet-fastnet","indonesia","bali","linknet","indosat","antar nusa","indo","firstmedia","s.i","cambodia","neuviz"];

  // Lowercased version of the ISP.
  var isp = data.org.toLowerCase();

  // Check if the lowercased ISP occurs in any of the organizations.
  var orgExists = organizations.some(org => org.includes(isp));

  // Ternary if statement.
  // If orgExists === true, text will be "exist: " + isp.
  // Otherwise text will be "no exist".
  var text = orgExists ? "exist: " + isp : "no exist";

  // Output the text.
  $("#ip").text(text);

});
```